# basic outgoing mail function

Tags: server, 14.04, postfix, mail

I've looked for tutorials and guides about this topic but seems really complicated to make it work.

I'm working with php, I would like to send mails in some scenarios such as password recovery and email confirmation... And I'm running all those projects in my Ubuntu 14.04 server as a vps digital ocean droplet... But after trying for days I can't make it works.... Since almost every guide is made as a full email server configuration

What I want is just to set a mail system which aloe me to send basic mail as I said before but having it secure and with a good performance....

What should I do? What's the best way to accomplish it? Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

PHP mail() function for sending basic email.

Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: aroll605, actually my app sends emails in the right way in a shared hosting (GoDaddy), but now i have decied to move to my own vps running ubuntu 14.04 server, so i have to set a mail server or any service just to send basic emails... but everything seems too hard to set up in almost every tut i find in the web...

Comment: Yes, that's what this function does. It's integrated into PHP and requires no setup. You just call it and it will send e-mail using linux sendmail application

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. They are asking for a way to setup `sendmail` (or something compatible).

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would highly recommend us use Mandrill via its RESTful API to handle your application generated outbound mail. This would provide you with templating, tracking, analytics, and help with spam filters. The cost is very reasonable too.

https://mandrill.com/

Comment: Yes it could be a solutions but any advice about how to set a bsic outgoing email server, secure and reliable?